# Подключиться к запароленному jupyter notebook в bat-файле

Tags: windows, сервер, bat, jupyter-notebook

Имеется запароленный файл jpnb, находящийся на компьютере у другого пользователя и доступный по ссылке.

*Мне нужно открыть и ввести пароль кодом bat-файла*

При переходе по ссылке запрашивается пароль.

**Я считаю, что если ссылка открывается, значит соединение с удаленным сервером уже установлено! *Если это не так, поправьте меня*.**

При открытии ссылки в браузере появляется окно ввода пароля. К сожалению, в bat-файле нельзя ввести пароль к странице в браузере. Поэтому я должна запустить jupyter notebook, указав конкретный порт, адрес хоста, пароль. (это все есть в ссылке). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашла ответ: подключение к серверу уже было, нужно было только при переходе по ссылке ввести пароль. Это делается в java-script-овом коде, встроенном в батник. 
Вот код, который мне помог - коротенький и очень простой:

```
@set @script=0 /*
@echo off
set @script=
@cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~dpnx0"
@exit /b
*/

var url,password;
url      = "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Documents/test.ipynb";
password = "1234567";
var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
IE.visible = 1;
IE.navigate(url); 

while (IE.Busy) {
  WScript.Sleep(200);
}

IE.document.getElementsByName("login")(0).value = login;
IE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).value = password;
button = IE.document.getElementsByClassName('ban ban-default')(0);
button.focus();
button.click();
```